# awk / bash : find max value in target column and save it as a shell variable

Tags: awk

I have a multi column pdb file in the following format:

```
TITLE     Guyana Rwanda Oman Macau Angola Cameroon Senegal
REMARK    THIS IS A SIMULATION BOX
CRYST1  110.021  109.621  137.004  90.00  90.00  90.00 P 1           1
MODEL        1
ATOM      1  N   GLY     1      69.549  60.748  48.309  1.004349.95           N
ATOM      5  CA  GLY     1      69.765  61.015  49.720  1.004349.95           C
ATOM      8  C   GLY     1      71.033  61.855  49.894  1.004349.95           C
ATOM      9  O   GLY     1      72.002  61.764  49.142  1.004349.95           O
ATOM     10  N   PRO     2      71.037  62.724  50.917  1.003607.69           N
ATOM     20  CA  PRO     2      72.090  63.773  51.194  1.003607.69           C
ATOM     22  C   PRO     2      73.563  63.267  51.418  1.003607.69           C
...
ATOM   3009  CA  PHE   193      67.584  61.241 143.505  1.002193.85           C
ATOM   3025  C   PHE   193      67.852  60.835 144.954  1.002193.85           C
ATOM   3026  O   PHE   193      67.517  61.508 145.936  1.002193.85           O
ATOM   3027  N   LYS   194      68.510  59.646 145.134  1.003060.31           N
ATOM   3029  CA  LYS   194      68.935  59.182 146.458  1.003060.31           C
ATOM   3047  C   LYS   194      70.263  59.758 146.902  1.003060.31           C
ATOM   3048  O   LYS   194      71.169  59.857 146.060  1.003060.31           O
ATOM   3049  N   SER   195      70.336  60.344 148.107  1.004127.85           N
ATOM   3051  CA  SER   195      71.608  60.918 148.699  1.004127.85           C
ATOM   3058  C   SER   195      72.652  59.977 149.153  1.004127.85           C
ATOM   3059  O   SER   195      73.689  60.436 149.679  1.004127.85           O
ATOM   3060  OXT SER   195      72.462  58.735 149.132  1.004127.85           O
TER
ENDMDL
```

Ignoring the first 4 and the last 2 lines (which does not fit to the 9 column format) I need to find the biggest number in the 9th column ( in this case 1.004349.95), and print only the relevant parts (4349.95) after the last zero, in the bash variable.

I would do it via AWK called from bash and stored result as $max_value in the following manner:

```
max_value="$(awk -v max=0 '{if($9>max){want=$2; max=$1}}END{print want} ' input.pdb)"
```

however my awk code does not work

Comment: What's the condition to care about a line? Keywords? Number of columns? You say 9 column format but I'm counting 10 columns on the ATOM lines. And what makes 4349.95 the "relevant part"?

Comment: Your last column has alphabetic characters. The actual column you appear to be the next to last. The strings in that column are not numbers - they are sequences of digits and decimal points, the fact that there are two decimal points is what makes the strings non-numerical - therefore they can't be compared numerically. You could possible split the "1." from the beginning of the string and compare the rest of the string as numbers.

Comment: `1.004349.95` is not even a valid number. What part of this should be truncated to make it a valid number?

Comment: Also you set `max` to `$1` which is always "ATOM" so your comparison is always against that.

Comment: Try `awk '/ATOM/{print substr($9, 5, length($9))}' input.pdb | sort | tail -1`

Comment: There's a problem with the PDB: the `tempFactor` field should be in `%6.2f` format but here you got a `%7.2f`. You might not be able to process the file with any standard PDB tool. Are you trying to normalize this value?

Comment: actually this is produced directly by gromacs and the pdb tool which I am using (chimerax) recognize correctly the format

Comment: please update the question with the desired output; while you state the output should be `4349.95`, your code does `print want` => `print $2` => prints a value from the 2nd column (integers in the range `1` to `3060`); it's also not clear (to me) the expected output if/when you have multilpe lines with the same 'max` value (eg, there are 4 lines with `4349.95` so, do you want to see 1 line of output or 4 lines of output?)

Comment: if the 9th column in 2 different lines happen to be `1.004349.95` and `2.004349.95`, which one is considered the 'max'? or are they considered the same? we need more details on the format of the 9th column; if the 9th column can start with something other than `1` then the sample should be updated to demonstrate this as well as explain how to process the 9th column

Comment: you state *`print only the relevant parts ... after the last zero`* but you don't define what you mean by 'last zero'; in the case of `1.003060.31`, if we take the *'relevant parts ... after the last zero'* we're left with `.31` ... ???

Comment: for 1.003060. it should be 3060.31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the tempFactor value according to the PDB spec, with the addition of the 10 following chars, as your PDB doesn't follow the spec:

```bash
awk '
    /^ATOM / && max < (val = substr($0, 61, 16) + 0) { max = val }
    END { print max+0 }
' file.pdb
```

Comment: i've just tested your solution: actually it does not find the max values since it ignores column if it have one more number e.g. like 1.003365.65           N

Comment: @JamesStarlight the conversion to a number wasn't enforced; it should work now

Answer (score 3):

With finding maximum and further `sub` substitution:

```
max_val=$(awk 'NF>9{ max=($9 > max? $9 : max) }END{ sub(/^[0-9]+\.0+/, "", max); print max }' input.pdb)
```

---

```
echo $max_val 
4349.95
```

Comment: i've just checked it and it does not find a real max value .. :-( mb could be another vay for awk to count it e.g starting from the back of the flot number ?

Comment: @JamesStarlight, share a link on the pdb file, and denote what's your expected "real max value"